# How to configure DNS for www and other sub-domains in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, dns, subdomain, plesk

In IIS7 I have two domains configured with one site, I mean they exists in the same physical path.

If I type principal.com or copy.com in the browser, both show the same content and that is ok.
But if I type www.copy.com it does not resolve to www.principal.com which is working fine.
So I think it's a DNS misconfiguration.

Also the subdomains related to copy.com does not resolve, for example subdomain.copy.com.
I configured the domain copy.com with plesk and it seems to have a master zone file with these entries: [*.copy.com.|A|173.201.16.246][www.copy.com.|A|173.201.16.246]

This information is been displayed within plesk but when I enter to the remote server and double check named.conf inside plesk/dns/etc, I can't see any entry for copy.com. There's not any mx file within plesk/dns/var related to copy.com

If the domain and DNS were created since 6 days ago.
What do you suggest?.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have described, the problem seems to be that the binding only exist for host names `principal.com` and `copy.com`. Add the bindings for `www.principal.com` and `www.copy.com` in the same manner. This of course assumes that your DNS records for all 4 domains point to same IP (173.201.16.246) and the site is configured to run on that IP. DNS configuration these days take few minutes to propagate, so 6 days is more than enough.

Comment: I have the bindings for the 4 domains and within plesk the 4 domains are pointing to the same IP. I tried to use nslookup using the nameserver of copy.com and that is what it responds: ns1.impresoresprofesionales.com cannot found copy.com:Server failed

Comment: In that case you have DNS resolution problem. You probably need an entry for copy.com. Someone on serverfault.com can help you in this much quicker.